# What summary statistics are best to recreate a distribution?

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics

I am working on a product where some sensors capture data at 500Hz (500 observations per second) and some sensors capture data at 30Hz.

Both are connected to the primary device which sends events back to the server at the end of 2 minute intervals (to batch process).

How can I best recreate the distribution by sending as little data as possible to the server? The goal will be to recreate distributions effectively and catch outliers from the sensor data. It's safe to assume that sending all the sensor data is not an option (very high bandwidth).

For example:

1. I could send mean, std deviation and median of the events over the 2 minute interval.
   (the underlying distributions are not normal though).
2. I could send p0, p10, p20, p30....p100 over the 2 minute interval.

Is there any standard approach to doing this using statistics ? (not using compression)

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! While this question is on-topic here, you might have better luck on the signal processing Stack.

Comment: (1) You say "...recreate the distribution by sending as little data as possible...."  Do you want to recreate the _sample_ or to estimate the _distribution_ of the population from which the sample was (systematically, if not randomly) taken? (2) When data are taken, what do you get? A 0 or 1? A count of something? Or a (rounded) observation from a continuous distribution?

Comment: I'd send moments

Comment: How do you measure whether a technique like your example 1 or 2 is successful at catching outliers?